# Is there a setting to make XCode give a prompt before running with warnings?

Tags: xcode, warnings, prompt, setting

I make an effort never to allow warnings to stay in my code, so usually when they occur I don't actually want to run my application because I did something stupid.  Therefore, I've tried to get in the habit of hitting Command-B to check warnings out before I run, but I slip a lot and hit Command-R instead.  Is there a setting in XCode that will display a prompt asking whether to continue or not if there are warnings after I hit 'build and run'?  I know about the setting "Treat all warnings as errors" but I would prefer not to use this, as I would have to turn it on and off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Xcode 4 this is no longer an issue.  You can use behaviors.